# Why did not M.K. Gandhi support plea towards suspension of Bhagat Singh, Rajguru, Sukhdev's execution?

Tags: indian

It was a known fact and most of the historians state that there was a clash of opinions, ideologies between these two individuals - `Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (M.K. Gandhi)` and `Bhagat Singh`, where MK Gandhi was in support of Non-Violence to Freedom and Bhagat Singh was in support of Rebellion (I would prefer calling it Rebellion, instead of calling it Violence)

It was shocking to see that there aren't any valid attempts made to plea (to the British government) for the suspension of execution. There are vague references on [this](http://www.mkgandhi.org/articles/bhagat_singh.htm) site that there were attempts made by Mr. MK Gandhi towards a plea on suspension of execution of these martyrs trio (Bhagat Singh, Rajguru, Sukhdev).

Are there are any valid references other than what I've stated, as I consider it  an attempt only to clear Gandhi's name and the criticism around this issue.

I would appreciate if there is any valid citation that talks about this matter other than the vague attempts to convey this point, in any of the bio-pics, biographies of Late Bhagat Singh.

Comment: I downvote all posts that reference but do not cite "well known fact"

Comment: @MarkCWallace, I don't mind your downvote but I would be interested to find out any citations referring to the incident mentioned

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer It's well known that many sources (including biopics of Bhagat Singh) make this claim, but it is **not** well known that it's a fact. If you're claiming that it is, then you should present a valid reference (i.e. one that doesn't have a hidden agenda) supporting your claim.